# How to add text after the nth occurrence in bash?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

Let's say I have helloworld.txt:

```
hello world
```

Using sed:

```
sed 's/w*/goodbye/' helloworld.txt
```

Gives me:

```
goodbyehello world
```

And:

```
sed 's/$/goodbye/' helloworld.txt
```

Gives me:

```
hello worldgoodbye
```

But how do I add text ***after*** the first occurrence, so it looks like this:

```
hellogoodbye world
```

Comment: try `sed 's/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\1 goodbye \2/' <<< 'hello world'`

Comment: that works if I remove the space between the 1 and goodbye -- `sed 's/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\1goodbye \2/' <<< 'hello world'`

Comment: Sure, if it works for you then use it.

Comment: Maybe `hello world` was a bad example? Let's say we were working with `7DF258  01DB-MET-RX PASS`. And I want to add `FIDUCIAL` after `7DF258` so it looks like: `7DF258FIDUCIAL 01DB-MET-RX PASS`. Or maybe I want to add it after `01DB-MET-RX` so it looks like `7DF258  01DB-MET-RXFIDUCIAL PASS`. I don't know. I used "nth" and "occurrence" as descriptors because it sounded right in my head, only -- I don't know any better; I'm still really knew to this.

Comment: @noob_basher Maybe you should update your question with real data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about inserting text before or after specific occurrences of *words* in a line of text.

```
$ echo 'word1 word2 word3 word4' | sed 's/\<[[:alnum:]]\{1,\}\>/newword &/'
newword word1 word2 word3 word4
```

```
$ echo 'word1 word2 word3 word4' | sed 's/\<[[:alnum:]]\{1,\}\>/& newword/'
word1 newword word2 word3 word4
```

```
$ echo 'word1 word2 word3 word4' | sed 's/\<[[:alnum:]]\{1,\}\>/& newword/2'
word1 word2 newword word3 word4
```

```
$ echo 'word1 word2 word3 word4' | sed 's/\<[[:alnum:]]\{1,\}\>/& newword/3'
word1 word2 word3 newword word4
```

```
$ echo 'word1 word2 word3 word4' | sed 's/\<[[:alnum:]]\{1,\}\>/& newword/4'
word1 word2 word3 word4 newword
```

This inserts the string `newword` (and a preceding space) in different locations in the given string.

The `sed` expression

```
s/\<[[:alnum:]]\{1,\}\>/& newword/2
```

will substitute the 2nd match of a non-empty string consisting of only alphanumerical characters.

The flanking `\<` and `\>` matches the zero-width boundary between a word and a non-word at the start and end of the match respectively (in GNU `sed`, you could also use `\b` for these). This ensures that you match whole words, but is not really needed with the given data (I use the word-boundary patterns because it emphasizes the intention of what I'm doing).

The `\{1,\}` is  a modifier that is written `+` in an extended regular expression and makes the preceding pattern match at least once (but `sed` uses basic regular expressions by default).

In the replacement part, `&` will be the bit of the input string that actually matches the pattern, and the `2` at the end is a flag that makes the substitution happen for the 2nd non-overlapping match only.

The examples [in your comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/573887/how-to-add-text-after-the-nth-occurrence-in-bash#comment1068367_573887) (which is almost the same but without inserting the space):

```
$ echo '7DF258 01DB-MET-RX PASS' | sed 's/\<[[:alnum:]-]\{1,\}\>/&FIDUCIAL/'
7DF258FIDUCIAL 01DB-MET-RX PASS
```

```
$ echo '7DF258 01DB-MET-RX PASS' | sed 's/\<[[:alnum:]-]\{1,\}\>/&FIDUCIAL/2'
7DF258 01DB-MET-RXFIDUCIAL PASS
```

Note that in the  example that you gave in comments, the "words" also contains dashes, this is why I use `[[:alnum:]-]` rather than just `[[:alnum:]]`.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. What if I don't know what the word is and I only know where I want to add the text -- which is after word 1,2,3,4 or 5?

Comment: @noob_basher I believe that is exactly what I'm showing. I'm going to add the example from your comment too.

Comment: Sorry! I just saw it! Thanks! Everything you posted was super helpful and much appreciated.